# Clear data form submit button php

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form and I want, when I click on submit button, that all data input will clear. My script below is not working:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.product_submit button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('span.loadding').html('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    var data_form = $("#form-product").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: location,
      data: data_form,
      success: function(resulf) {
        var errors = $(resulf).find('#alert_order').html();
        var html = $(resulf).find('#add-to-order-success').html();
        if (html) {
          $('#add-to-order-success').html(html);
          $(".myform")[0].reset();
        }
        if (errors) {
          $('#add-to-order-success').html(errors);
        }
        $('span.loadding').html('<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
      }
    })
  })
});

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="form-add-cart">
  <form method="post" action="" id="form-product" name="myform">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="40%">
            <?php _e('Họ và tên:','wow'); ?>
          </td>
          <td width="60%"><input type="text" name="name_order" value="<?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?>" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="40%">
            <?php _e('Điện thoại:','wow'); ?>
          </td>
          <td width="60%"><input type="text" name="phone_order" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="40%">
            <?php _e('Sản phẩm :','wow'); ?>
          </td>
          <td width="60%"><input type="text" name="product_order" value="<?php the_title();  ?>" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" required></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="product_submit">
      <button type="submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
                    <?php _e('Gửi','wow'); ?>   <span class="loadding"></span>
                </button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="add_product_to_order" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: “not working” is not a problem description. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. What is the specific problem and what is the expected result?

Comment: form sent data, but don't reset data input when click submit.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the problem is that you didn't include `class="myform"` in your form.

As you can see, you are applying to the `reset()` class myform.

`$(".myform")[0].reset();`

You can alternatively set an id to it like `id="myidform"`

and then use it in you jquery

`$("#myidform")[0].reset();`

Comment: that is name of form :(

Comment: please set a class name of in your form something like

`<form class="yourclassnameform">`....

and then use it in your jquery

`$(".yourclassnameform")[0].reset();`

Comment: @HoàngAnh have you tested it?

Comment: i use : $('input[type="text"],textarea').val('');, and it worked for me.
Thank for support :)